# What figure of speech is this

Tags: irony

> Ageing is affected by the passage of time. To cure ageing - stop time!

I don't think this is irony, sarcasm or paradoxical but I'm sure there's a word to describe the "stop time" element.

What is it, please? Absurdity?

Comment: **Truism**: a ​statement that is so ​obviously ​true that it is ​almost not ​worth saying.

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to stop time!

Comment: Also a truism ;)

Comment: **Absurdity** applies, or depending on how the rest of the context unfolds, perhaps only an attention-grabbing phrase that will turn out to mean something other than what it actually says: "Live longer. Stop time. Come to the relaxing beaches of Tahiti, a paradise where time seems to stand still."

Answer (score 2):

"Stopping time" is something that you can never do. It is one of (extravagant) exaggerations called [***hyperbole***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbole), which means:

Deliberate or unintentional overstatement, particularly extreme overstatement.

It can be also truism as Joe Dark mentioned, but I think it is closer to hyperbole.

You can read a lot of [exmples](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-hyperboles.html) in the link.

I will love you *until the end of time*. I'll love you *till the ocean*.